# How to check which guard we are currently within in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, guard

I have here a portion of my header.blade.php file of a project.

```
                    @guest   
                    @else
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true">
                            {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
                            </a> 
                             @if(condition here)
                             $profile='/myprofile';
                             $logout='/logout';
                             @else
                             $profile='/admin/myprofile';
                             $logout='/admin/logout';
                             @endif
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                  <li><a href="{{$profile}}">My Profile</a></li>
                               <li>  <a href="{{$logout}}">Log Out</a>                                   
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                              @endif
                        </li>
                    @endguest
```

I have 2 guards namely web and admin. I want the `$profile` and `$logout` to be `'/profile'` and `'/logout'` && `'/admin/profile'` and `'/admin/logout'` respectively for each of the 2 guards.

Now I know that I can check for each guard as `Auth::guard('name')->check();`
But, when both the guards are logged in at the same time, it creates a sort of problem this way.i.e.

```
     if(Auth::guard('web')->check())
{$profile="/myprofile";}
if(Auth::guard('admin')->check())
{$profile="/admin/myprofile";}
```

Since both will be active, $profile will have the latter value in every case.
So, is there a way such that this problem can be addressed?
Something like

```
if(Auth::guard()=='admin'){
////////////////
}
```

which of course doesn't work.

Comment: if both guards are active then it is a matter of preference as to which guard you want to check.

Comment: Thanks Sapnesh. Cheers mate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess youll have to have separate headers for each of the interfaces taken care by each of your guards. Clearly`if(Auth::guard()=='admin'){
////////////////
}` is not valid without mentioning the guard name

Comment: Id figured that out a long time ago but still thanks for bothering to answer.